# Logstash parsing 2021-04-23T09:00:12.256466 from CSV

Tags: logstash

I have a csv file with datetime and a name

```
2021-04-23 09:00:12.256466,4454.34
```

How do I parse this via logstash so that I get the first column as @timestamp

I have tried

```
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["datetime","value"]
      convert => {
                        "value" => "float"
                }
       }
       date {
            match => ["datetime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"]
            target => "datetime"
       }
}
```

But this did not help. I tried other combinations also but nothing is working

Comment: When facing such situations with timestamps in logstash I use following online tool for finding out the matching pattern: http://staging-jodadebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Are you getting a _dateparsefailure tag?

Comment: @Badger am not getting error, just that it is not storing it in \@timestamp

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["datetime","value"]
      convert => {
                        "value" => "float"
                }
       }
       date {
            match => ["datetime", "ISO8601"]
            target => "@timestamp"
       }
}
```

Although with this I am not able to capture upto microseconds, as this captures up to milliseconds only